# Rename column with reserved word as column name; Works on one, fails on another

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm renaming two columns in two tables, both of which are named LEVEL, which is a reserved word.

What is confusing me greatly is that I am running an identical command on both these tables, but only one of them is failing. Here are the commands:

```
--this works
ALTER TABLE notificationsubscriptions RENAME COLUMN "LEVEL" TO nlevel;
--this doesn't
ALTER TABLE notifications RENAME COLUMN "LEVEL" TO nlevel;
```

The second statement results in the following error:

```
Error starting at line : 9 in command -
ALTER TABLE notifications RENAME COLUMN "LEVEL" TO nlevel
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Both these columns are of the same datatype (number). I am baffled - Why would this command work for one of these tables but not the other?

The database is running Oracle 10.2.

Comment: Can you show us your SQL*Plus session?

Comment: You may need a slash between the two statements.

Comment: Run properly, both those statements work.  So that error means there's something iffy in the way you're running them.

Comment: run as script and not as sql statement

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove any links that exist on this column from indexes and/or foreign key constraints

- Drop indexes
- Rename column
- Create indexes with the new name of column